# Division theorems

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

**I want to make a summary of the division theorems in my textbook.**

**The next theorems are given as $\Rightarrow$, which are also true as $⟺$?**

*Given:*

- $a,b,c,d,m,n∈\mathbb{Z}$
- $p,q∈\mathbb{P} $ (prime numbers)
- $i∈{1,…,k}$

*Theorems:*

1. $a|b \wedge  b|c \Rightarrow a|c $
2. $c|a  \wedge  c|b \Rightarrow c|(ma+nb)$
3. $a|c  \wedge  b|c  \wedge  (a,b)=1 \Rightarrow ab|c  $
4. $p|a  \wedge  q|a \Rightarrow pq|a $
5. $a∤c  \wedge  b∤c \Rightarrow ab∤c $
6. $a∤c  \wedge  b|c \Rightarrow ab∤c $
7. $a∤c  \vee  b∤c \Rightarrow ab∤c $
8. $a|bc \Rightarrow a|b  \vee  a|c $
9. $p|ab \Rightarrow p|a  \vee  p|b $
10. $a|bc  \wedge  (a,b)=1 \Rightarrow a|c $
11. $a|b \Rightarrow ac|bc   $
12. $a|n \wedge a≤n \Rightarrow a|n!  $
13. $a|n \wedge a<n \Rightarrow a|(n-1)!  $
14. $p|(a_1⋅a_2⋅…⋅a_k) \Rightarrow p| a_i  $ for some $i$
15. $b=pq \wedge (a,b)=1 \Rightarrow(a,p)=1 \wedge (a,q)=1 $
16. $(a,b)=d \Rightarrow(\frac{a}{d},\frac{b}{d})=1$

**UPDATE: Correct answers**

1. $a|b \wedge  b|c \Rightarrow a|c $
2. $c|a  \wedge  c|b \Rightarrow c|(ma+nb)$
3. $a|c  \wedge  b|c  \wedge  (a,b)=1 \Rightarrow ab|c  $
4. $p|a  \wedge  q|a ⟺ pq|a $
5. $a∤c  \vee  b∤c ⟺ ab∤c $
6. $a|bc \Leftarrow a|b  \vee  a|c $
7. $p|ab ⟺ p|a  \vee  p|b $
8. $a|bc  \wedge  (a,b)=1 \Rightarrow a|c $
9. $a|b  ⟺ ac|bc$ with $c\neq 0$
10. $a|n \Rightarrow a|n!  $
11. $a|n \wedge a<n \Rightarrow a|(n-1)!  $
12. $p|(a_1⋅a_2⋅…⋅a_k) ⟺ p| a_i  $ for some $i$
13. $b=pq \wedge (a,b)=1 \Rightarrow(a,p)=1 \wedge (a,q)=1 $
14. $(a,b)=d ⟺(\frac{a}{d},\frac{b}{d})=1$

Comment: Any thoughts yourself?

Comment: @Bram28 I added it to the question.

Comment: For 3:  if you don;t have (a,b)=1, but just a|c and b|c you can't guarantee ab|c: take a=b=c=2.  And you're right, 8 does *not* go from left to right! (it does go from right to left, which is what I was looking at! :) ).  Anyway, counterexample to 8: b=2, c=3, a=6.  P.s. we shouldn't have this conversation under Jose's post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. To be more precise:

2) $c\mid a\wedge c\mid b\iff(\forall m,n\in\mathbb{Z}):c\mid ma+nb$

4) If $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes, then $p\mid a\wedge q\mid a\iff pq\mid a$

11) If $c\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus{0}$, then $a\mid b\iff ac\mid bc$.

Comment: @bram28 just said that 2 is only ⇒?

Comment: Not my fault. The statement that I wrote *is* an equivalence. The other user provided a counter-example to another statement.

Comment: Indeed, so this counter-example shows that 2) is only ⇒? Or am I wrong?

Comment: @LeneCoenen The difference is that Jose puts the universal on the right side of the $\Leftrightarrow$, while I interpreted your statement 2 to be: $\forall a,b,c,m,n (c | a \land c \ b \Rightarrow c | (ma+nb))$, i.e. I put the universal *outside* the whole biconditional ... so .. this is something that should be clarified

Comment: @Bram28 What is the difference if the universal is on the right side? I only learned about theorems where the universal is outside the whole biconditional.

Comment: @LeneCoenen Sure, in both statements the universal stands for everything, but in general the statement $P \leftrightarrow \forall x \ Q(x)$ is not logically equivalent to $\forall x \ (P \leftrightarrow  Q(x))$

Comment: @Bram28 Thnx. So from al the 16 theorems only nr. 4, 8, 9, 11, 14 and 16 are true as ⟺?

Comment: @LeneCoenen With the suitable clarifications, that would be my answer, yes.

Comment: @Bram28 Why does nr. 3 require (a,b)=1? Book also says Nr. 8 is not correct, only nr 9 works, why?

Comment: @LeneCoenen Note that $4\mid12$ and $6\mid12$, but $(4\times6)\nmid12$. No. 8 is false: $6\mid(2\times3)$, but $6\nmid2$ and $6\nmid3$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I just updated the question with your marks. Would you please just check one more time if everything is ok now? Thnx!

Comment: @LeneCoenen It seems right. You should add a few words; for instance, you should say that $p$ and $q$ always stand for prime numbers. Note that in no. 12 there is a useless hypethesis, which is that $a\leqslant n$; thet follows from the fact that $a\mid n$. No. 16 is an equivalence under the assumption that $d\mid a\wedge d\mid b$.

Answer (score 0):

$2$ isn't. Counterexample: $c=2, m=n=a=b=1$

$14$ needs to be clarified ... I suppose you mean $p|a_i$ for *some* $i$

For $16$ ... assuming $a/d$ and $b/d$ are well-defined, i.e. are whole numbers, then that one goes both ways.

$8$ and $9$ go both ways